# Heroko application error with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

First time using Heroko. Followed the steps and my build was successful but when I go to the URL I got an application error. I looked in the logs but I'm not really sure whats happening, below is the list of logs I had

```
    2016-08-04T14:24:15.352519+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-08-04T14:24:31.776384+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2016-08-04T14:24:34.211793+00:00 app[web.1]: keyword api listening at http://[::]:8088
2016-08-04T14:25:32.328147+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-08-04T14:25:32.327930+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-08-04T14:25:32.501167+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-08-04T14:25:32.503024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-08-04T14:25:32.477573+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-08-04T14:25:36.445941+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2016-08-04T14:25:39.335482+00:00 app[web.1]: keyword api listening at http://[::]:8088
2016-08-04T14:26:37.186681+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-08-04T14:26:37.186681+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-08-04T14:26:37.329330+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-08-04T14:26:37.353704+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-08-04T14:26:37.619772+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=shielded-temple-17247.herokuapp.com request_id=db8eb419-e950-4768-8a3f-319a84f7d4e2 fwd="2.125.30.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-08-04T14:26:38.809203+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shielded-temple-17247.herokuapp.com request_id=5661b532-80af-40cb-8ae3-0bf9868b5e0f fwd="2.125.30.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: seems like you have a problem with the port that use your application. Heroku sets a diferent port when it start running.

Answer (score 0):

What do you have defined in your `Procfile`? Right now, it appears to be something like this:

```
web: node server.js
```

The `Procfile` tells Heroku how to run your application. The logs you showed indicate that you are trying to run your Node server on port `8088` -- this is likely the issue.

Heroku doesn't allow you to run your server on ANY port you want -- instead, it will dynamically tell you what port to run your server on when your application starts. It does this through the usage of an environment variable named `PORT`.

What you need to do is modify your `server.js` code so that you start your server on `process.env.PORT`.

Here's an example (in express.js):

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

That will successfully start up a Node server on Heroku by automatically binding to the correct port.

Hope that helps!